# Index Match Formula Keeps Continuing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to create a dashboard, where upon selecting a company from a dropdown list, it will list all of the company's bankers where the data is on another worksheet tab.

So far, the Index Match formula seems to be running fine, however, it keeps on running and lists the bankers from other companies. How can I fix this?

File can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fw7yh4AEF1vx3cuG6E_1RBTrTD_k74KD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below approach by pasting below formula in cell `E5`:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(RAW!$D$2:$D$279,SMALL(IF(RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5,ROW(RAW!$D$2:$D$279)-1,10^10),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

This is array formula so it needs to be committed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and then copy it down as much needed.

**Explanation:**

`INDEX` is retrieves the range reference from the defined GRID based on the row and column reference.

In this particular case, we intend to extract the references sequentially. This is performed by `SMALL(IF(RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5,ROW(RAW!$D$2:$D$279)-1,10^10),ROWS($A$1:A1))`

Within this formula, first portion is the ARRAY building IF formula as below

`IF(RAW!$B$2:$B$279=$C$5,ROW(RAW!$D$2:$D$279)-1,10^10)` which tests cells in column B if they match criterion value. If the value matches then ROW reference is returned and if it doesn't then it returns a very large value i.e. 10^10. We subtract 1 from row reference as the data starts from row 2 so it should be (n-1) in principle. This arrangement produces an ARRAY like `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;10000000000....}` for value "Acorda".

But we need to pass one element at a time to INDEX formula so this is done by `SMALL(IfBasedArray,k)` where k part is serially generated by `ROWS($A$1:A1)` which starts with 1 and increments downwards as the formula gets copied which thus enables INDEX to return desired results.

Finally, when the matches are finished then big number i.e. 10000000000 gets fed and generates an error which then is covered by IFERROR formula to return blank!

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you. 

This provided the correct solution. If you mind, you help break down the formula so I can understand the logic behind this? Very much appreciated if otherwise.

Comment: Would you happen to know why the formula repeats the results for 'Pacira Biosciences'?

Here is a screenshot of what's happening

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AYJjnJ8LMe_A0XpcziUicawuLSuoMqcy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Rich if you still have not figured out then please check Row 122 and then Row 234 in your sample file. You should be able to find your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this formula to your sheet's E5 and copy down. Note that I created the named range `Coms` which refers to RAW!B2:B279.

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Coms,MATCH($C$5,Coms,0)+ROW()-ROW(E$5))=$C$5,INDEX(Coms,MATCH($C$5,Coms,0)+ROW()-ROW(E$5)),""),"")
```

If you prefer, the name in the formula can be replaced with the address, as you had it originally, or you define the named range to expand dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option than the 2 previous answers (doesn't require an CSE array entered formula or multiple nested INDEX/MATCHES) would be to have a couple of 'helper' cells in say G5/G6

Start Row would be `=MATCH(C5,RAW!B:B,0)` This finds the first row on your RAW sheet where the selected company appears

Advisor Count would be `=COUNTIFS(RAW!B:B,C5)` counts how many rows there are for this particular company

Then your formula in cell E5 becomes `=IF(D5<=$G$6,INDEX(RAW!$D:$D,$G$5+D5-1),"")` which you can drag down.

[screenshot showing formulas/result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmwBP.jpg)